# How can i use json data in a template that i want to convert using angular2react package. I want to make it dynamic but template is static

Tags: templates, json

I want to take json data and put it in my template. Actually i am using angular2react package to use angularjs code in my reactjs project

This is my component:
const component= {
    template :`<input type=\"number\" ng-model=\"size\" name=\"size\" min=\"0\" max=\"10\" integer />{{size}}<br />`

}

export default component;

This is the json data:

"modelView": {
      "components": [
         {
            "resource": "virtualDomains.StudentCourseList",
            "name": "Testingpageresource",
            "type": "resource",
            "staticData": []
         },
         {
            "components": [
               {
                  "allowDelete": false,
                  "components": [
                     {
                        "readonly": false,
                        "name": "Testingpageblock_grid_text",
                        "model": "SCBCRSE_CRSE_NUMB",
                        "label": "Testingpageblock_grid_text",
                        "loadInitially": true,
                        "type": "text",
                        "parameters": {},
                        "validation": {},
                        "required": false
                     },
                     {
                        "readonly": false,
                        "name": "Testingpageblock_grid_child_2",
                        "model": "SCBCRSE_EFF_TERM",
                        "label": "Testingpageblock_grid_child_2",
                        "loadInitially": true,
                        "type": "text",
                        "parameters": {},
                        "validation": {},
                        "required": false
                     }
                  ],
                  "onSave": "alert(\"Something\");",
                  "onError": "{{size}}
",
                  "allowNew": true,
                  "pageSize": 5,
                  "loadInitially": true,
                  "type": "grid",
                  "name": "Testingpageblock_grid",
                  "allowModify": true,
                  "model": "Testingpageresource",
                  "allowReload": true,
                  "parameters": {}
               }

I need the onError data and need to put it in the template to be able to use for angular2react

Comment: I got the solution for this.
But if Someone finds a solution please respond because it can be better than mine

Answer (score 0):

It's good to start with what version of EE you're working with so we all know.

I'm not familiar with the angularjs package you're using, but I know how to get tag data into your templates.

First you need an add-on that is installed where you can work with your json object in php and parse into tagdata. (if you don't have this there's a whole process that I can go over with you)

Assuming the class for this method is named `My_class`, you would have a method within it that looks something like this:

```
function get_on_error_tagdata ( $json ) {
    $object = json_decode( $json, true );
    $variables = array();
    foreach ( $object['onError'] as $key => $value ) {
        $variables[$key] = $value
    }
    return ee()->TMPL->parse_variables_row( ee()->TMPL->tagdata, $variables );
}
```

Now, I'm not sure how you're getting your `$json` object in the first place, but assuming you already have it you'll have to work with it to make sure it's parsed into the `$variables` array properly, but once you have that you'll be able to access those values on the frontend like this:

```
{exp:my_class:get_on_error_tagdata}
    {allowNew}
    {pageSize}
    {loadInitially}
    {type}
    {etc}
{/exp:my_class:get_on_error_tagdata}
```

You can also pass values to your class using that tag as well by adding `my_value='{whatever data you want the class to have}'` inside the opening tag and inside of your method add `$value = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('my_value');`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out myself